# Java - Transferring BufferedImage through TCP Socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, bufferedimage

I am not very good in Java, and I need to send a BufferedImage through a TCP socket. I already managed to make a connection (and send strings), but I couldn't really find out which Writer I should use in order to send and recover the BufferedImage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending a screenshot (bufferedImage) over a socket in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973848/sending-a-screenshot-bufferedimage-over-a-socket-in-java)

Comment: I didn't find that one while searching, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should `ImageIO.write` to serialize an image as a byte stream using some format (PNG, JPG, etc.).

Then you should send the byte stream over wire. The difficulty here is you don't know the size of the stream ahead. Simple solution is save all content into in-memory byte array (use ByteArrayOutputStream for it) then send it. Or if it doesn't fit into memory you should do something smart (save it into temporary file, or use some chunked protocol or send unique terminator mark).

Comment: @Arin It is so many options how it could be implemented... So, it is difficult to come up with a definitive sample. In most situations it's better not to use raw TCP, but use e.g. HTTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438375/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-image-to-display-on-jsp

Comment: @Arin Here is an example with an in-memory storage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4944536/438742

Answer (score 0):

See the [`ImageIO` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) which contains methods for [reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) and writing [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)s and [`RenderedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html)s to/from various input/output streams.